# Should the mods migrate this question from History.SE to C.SE?

Tags: discussion, migration

[This question asks about bilbical prophets](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/56153/16773), and is being closed at the moment, with some push back from members that "religious texts" are not valid sources. (Which is a load of nonsense, given that there is indeed some historical/chronological information in the OT).

Should we move this to CSE?

Comment: I'd say no. It could be reasked here, but even then I'm not sure it would really fit.

Comment: @curiousdannii OK, thanks for the feedback